# Solving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})$ using Abel's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am looking for some help with an real analysis problem that I have.

Problem: 
Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})=1-(1/2)+(1/3)-(1/4)+\ldots $

What I have so far:
My intuition suggests that I could use Abel's theorem which states that if $G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ is a power series with real coefficients converges and the radius of convergence is 1, then $\lim_{x\to1^{-}}G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$.

So then I tried to rewrite the power series given in the problem to have a starting index of 0. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k+1}=\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\ln(1+x)=ln(2)$ which I think would hold because the radius of convergence of $\ln(1+x)$ is 1. I am not sure if this is the right idea or not.

Comment: That is basically it: you are using that if $\sum a_n$ converges, its limit is also $\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum a_nx^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n} & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^1(-1)^{n}x^ndx\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-x^n)dx
\end{split}
$$
where the integral and sum can be swapped by the dominated convergence theorem. Indeed
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^N(-x)^n \right|=\frac{1-(-x)^{N+1}}{1+x}\leq\frac{1}{1+x}$$
Consequently
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1\frac 1 {1+x}dx = \ln 2$$

Edit: I realized that the OP was explicitly asking for using Abel's theorem. So I'm not exactly answering the question. Sorry about that. Leaving this here, in case it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could use the Leibniz test (a special case of Abel's theorem), since the series is alternating and decreasing.

That is,  the series alternates and $\mid a_{n+1}\mid\lt\mid a_n\mid$.  So it converges.

Your idea appears to be correct.   See [Abel's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) .

Comment: True.  But this does not tell you the value of the series.  I assume that is what the OP means by *solving* the series.

Comment: Yes.  It does not.